# Invalid parameters in CGBitmapContext constructor

Tags: xamarin.ios, cgbitmapcontext

I'm trying to create a blank bitmap in a Xamarin.iOS project using the [CGBitmapContext constructor(s)](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContext/).  However, no matter what I try I just get the error `"System.Exception: Invalid parameters to context creation"`

Example code:

```
const int width = 100;
const int height = 100;
const int bytesPerPixel = 4;
const int bitsPerComponent = 8;
var intBytes = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
byte[] pixelData = new byte[intBytes];
var colourSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
using (var objContext = new CGBitmapContext(pixelData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, width * bytesPerPixel, colourSpace, CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrderDefault))
{
    // ...
}
```

I have tried changing most of the parameters; I tried fixing the data block and passing it as an IntPtr.  I tried using  null as the first parameter so that the system would allocate the data.  And I've tried various flags in the last parameter.  I always get that same error.  What parameter is wrong?  And what needs to be changed in the code above to make it  execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed last parameter from `CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrderDefault` to `CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedLast` , and the error disappear.

refer to [CGBitmapFlags Enumeration](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGBitmapFlags/)

As the link said

> This enumeration specifies the layout information for the component data in a bitmap.
>
> This enumeration determines the in-memory organization of the data and includes the color model, whether there is an alpha channel present and whether the component values have been premultiplied.

I think we have to select the corresponding flag to match the data info, especially the color model.

For the same reason, If you choose **CreateDeviceCmyk** , `CGBitmapFlags.None` will be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed worked.  I hadn't realised that the ColorSpace determined the arrangement of the bytes